# How to set which node a module loads on?

Tags: 6

I have a module that works on the hook_user (updates) it pushes details to another DB. I only want this module to load on the admin user edit screen where you can assign roles to a user. Currently I have a message that either says because you are role X you are allowed to send data, else sorry you do not have the rights to send data. However these messages display on every page in my drupal 6 website. I was wondering how I can limit this module to just the admin user edit screen, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check the current user having admin role, if you are using drupal superadmin, then check current logedin user's id equals 1.

```
<?php
  function custommodule1_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
    global $user;
    if($op == 'update') {
      if (in_array("administrator", $user->roles) || $user->uid == 1) {
          // Show message that only for admin.
          // Do whatever you want do for admin.
          drupal_set_message('You are Administrator you are allowed to send data');
      }
      else {
          // Show message for author users.
          drupal_set_message('Sorry you do not have the rights to send data');
      }
    }
  }
?>
```